# PHP psr-0 Namespace is not finding class

Tags: php

I get this error when doing a `psr-0` namespace.

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'myApp\Db' not found in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/elioop/User.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: Class 'myApp\Db' not found in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/elioop/User.php on line 7

I did a composer `dump-autoload -o`and still the error persists. The db and user files are within the directory, the root directory that is.

[image]

here is my current set up

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "poweruser/elioop",
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.8"
    },
    "autoload":{
      "psr-0":{
        "myApp": ""
      }
    }
}
```

**Db.php**

```
<?php
namespace myApp;


class Db{

    private $db;

    public function connect()
    {

        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=eli9;port=8889", 'root', 'root');
            $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
                return $db;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }


}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace myApp;

use myApp\Db;

class User extends Db{

    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->db = $this->connect();

    }
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
// Report simple running errors

require_once 'User.php';
$guest = new User();


$username = htmlentities(trim($_POST['txt_username']));
$unpass = htmlentities(trim($_POST['txt_password']));
$password = password_hash($unpass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 12] );
$unemail = $_POST['txt_email'];
$email = filter_var($unemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
......
```

Comment: use myApp\Db; in the User.php shold be removed - cause both of classes are in the same namespace

Comment: so what namespace should i use ?

Comment: just leave the whole file without that line :) them both are under namespace myApp;

Comment: i still get a `Class 'myApp\Db' not found` on line 6 of the user.php file

Comment: can you give the index.php file code?

Comment: sure, i just updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why PSR-0 and not PSR-4 ?

Also, you don't seem to be using the composer  PSR-0 autoloader. You should do:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; //Composer autoloader


session_start();
// Report simple running errors


$guest = new \myApp\User();
```

Once you've loaded the composer autoloader then all your composer autoloading configuration should take effect.

Comment: this works, and i will accept it as soon as it lets me, however it seems to mess up the pdo set up in the db.php file `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'myApp\PDO' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/elioop/Db.php:13`

Comment: Working with namespaces is tricky. If you're within a namespace then classes are  referenced relatively to the namespace so you need to either do `new \PDO` to indicate it's a root class or add a `use PDO` in the top under the namespace definition.

Comment: Ok thanks its working now. Appreciate your help sir :)